# How can I ensure the JSON:API response is using the most up-to-date revisions of my content?

Tags: caching

I am working on getting gatsby-source-drupal set up in order to use the useStaticQuery hook for some content on my site. From what I understand, I need to use the JSON API instead of Drupal views to fetch content from Drupal.

However, I've noticed that the JSON API response is not the most up-to-date version of my content. My coworkers and I set up our own endpoints that **do** return the most accurate and up-to-date content, but the JSON API data is many months outdated. Even when I try to filter my GraphQL query by revision timestamp and choose the most recent revision timestamp, I still get this same outdated content.

Does anyone know why this would be happening or how I can ensure the JSON API response is up-to-date? Thank you in advance!

Comment: JSON:API response should be whatever is in the cache, so if you clear caches, you should get an up-to-date response.

Comment: If you are getting stale content after updating it, you may need to invalidate a cache tag so that the next time the content is requested, the entity is rebuilt.

Comment: Old content in Drupal is usually due to missing or wrong cache metadata.